# how to get employee count by status in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have a requirement to count total number of employees with active status. I have emp status column and emp id column, please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: Pls show some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(table[id], 
    FILTER(
        table, 
        table[status] = "Active"
    )
)
```

Comment: DISTINCTCOUNT is only required if there are multiple row in the table for a employee. Other wise COUNT will also work which is better one. Overall this Measure should work.

Comment: @mkRabbani you are right. since there was only very little information in the question. i figured that it was better to be on the safe side and use distinctcount :-)

Comment: HI @nini, Please accepts the answer and put an up vote. only giving thanks is not sufficient here in SO :)